# Python converting '\' to '\\'

Tags: python, list, sorting, latex, append

I am writing a program to sort a list fo input strings (song names).
Those songnames contains latex chars like $\lambda$, which i want to 
get sorted like 'lambda' instead, så i'm using a the ability to apply
a function to each element during sort. like this:

```
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-
def conv( inp ):
    if inp == '$\lambda$':
        return 'lambda'
    else:
        return inp

mlist = []
mlist.append('martin')
mlist.append('jenny')
mlist.append('åse')
mlist.append('$\lambda$')
mlist.append('lambda')
mlist.append('\her')
print (mlist)
mlist = sorted(mlist, key=conv(str.lower))
print (mlist)
```

But for some reason, when i append the `lambda` sign or `\her` it converts it to `\\her` or `$\\lambda$`, can i prevent this?

Comment: Make sure you escape your backslashes with another backslash: `'$\\lambda$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But for some reason, when i append the `lambda` sign or `\her` it converts it to `\\her` or `$\\lambda$`...

No it doesn't. What you're seeing is the *representation*, which always doubles solo backslashes for clarity. If you *print* the actual strings instead you'll see that they're fine.

Comment: Thanks. Now i have a problem with the sort/replace thing.

i use:
    songs[] = sorted(key=str.replace('$\lambda$', 'lambda'))

But it says replace is only getting one argument... Can you help with this?

Comment: Separate questions should be posted as separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code: what you're experiencing is `repr` behaviour. Printing a list causes it's contents to be repr'd, and `repr` escapes `\`.

```
print repr(r'\foo') # => '\\foo'
```

If you want to print the list without `repr`, you use either a loop or str.join.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested you should escape your backslash:

```
'$\\lambda$'
```

Another alternative is to use raw strings, which are not subject to special character substitution:

```
r'$\lambda$'
```

When you have many backslashes raw strings tend to be clearer.

Comment: `\l` is not an escape sequence, `'$\lambda$'` yields the same string as `r'$\lambda$'`.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: You are right, I got confused with ^L. So, while my suggestion is sensible in a similar context, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour: as it is displaying the string stored in the list, and the double slashes means escaped slash. If you want to see the actual string, you should simply print that string, not the list. Try to append this line to your program:

```
print (' '.join(mlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you should use `r'$\lambda$'` moreover when you print the list it print a repr of each element to print

you should do

```
from __future__ import print_function
print (*mlist)
```